# Prisma Not Recognizing Defined `eventName` Argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

I'm using windows10 and
nodejs v20.11.1
prisma 5.11.0
and mongodb 7.0.6

in schema.prisma:

```
type intrack {
  eventName String
  eventData intrack_event_data
  userId    Int
}

model Productdg {
  id                   String               @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  intrack              intrack
...
}
```

get this when I try to create:
`` Unknown argument `eventName`. Available options are marked with ?. ``
and when remove eventName from data get this:
`` Argument `eventName` is missing. ``

it's work fine a minute ago and I insert some data but suddenly this hppend I try to remove node_module folder, remove cache and reinstall everything but nothing work other field is fine but only on intrack filed get error. this error is same for eventData and userId too.

Comment: Run `prisma generate`

Comment: Try that too, not working

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but the value of the userId field, which had Int type, was set to null, and instead of `` Argument `userId` is missing. ``, I was getting this error which has nothing to do with the value of the `eventName`.
fix by adding `?` to type:
`userId    Int?`

Comment: Maybe that answer should be better a comment on the question ...